# Speeding up differentiation of a complicated expression

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic

I'm a beginner to Mathematica in the spirit that I cannot write the most optimized codes for a particular task. In the following snippet, I have a function $\Phi(\eta(Ee,y,z),\alpha(y,Ee,z),\xi(\kappa,Ee,V,z,y))$ at the end of the line whose derivative with respect to $z$. I wish to calculate. The expressions for $\eta,\chi,\alpha,\xi$ have been defined earlier. The code has been running for about an hour and a half now and yet there has been no output. To put things in perspective, I have been able to calculate the derivatives by hand in about 5 minutes and have no clue why Mathematica is taking so long. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Apologies if I have made any formatting errors in my code

Note-The derivatives are to be evaluated at $z=0$

Thank You

```
    SetAttributes[V, Constant]

    Ee[x_, y_, z_] := 
    Assuming[Element[y, Reals] && Element[z, Reals] && 
    Element[x, Reals], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]];

   \[Eta][Ee[x_, y_, z_], z_] := 
    Assuming[Element[Ee, Reals] && Element[z, Reals], 
    Sqrt[(Ee[x, y, z] - z)/(Ee[x, y, z] + z)]];

   \[Alpha][y_, Ee[x_, y_, z_], z_] := 
    Assuming[Element[z, Reals] && Element[y, Reals] && 
    Element[Ee, Reals], ArcTan[y/Sqrt[Ee[x, y, z]^2 - y^2 - z^2]]];

   \[Kappa][y_, z_, Ee[x_, y_, z_], V_] := 
    Assuming[Element[y, Reals] && Element[z, Reals] && 
    Element[Ee, Reals] && Element[V, Reals], 
    Sqrt[y^2 + z^2 - (Ee[x, y, z] - V)^2]];

   \[Xi][\[Kappa][y_, z_, Ee[x_, y_, z_], V_], Ee[x_, y_, z_], V_, z_, 
    y_] := Assuming[
    Element[y, Reals] && Element[z, Reals] && Element[Ee, Reals] && 
    Element[V, 
     Reals], (\[Kappa][y, z, Ee[x, y, z], V] + y)/(Ee[x, y, z] - V + 
      z)];

   \[CapitalPhi][\[Eta][Ee[x_, y_, z_], z_], \[Alpha][y_, Ee[x_, y_, z_],
    z_], \[Xi][\[Kappa][y_, z_, Ee[x_, y_, z_], V_], Ee[x_, y_, z_], 
    V_, z_, y_]] := 
    2*ArcTan[\[Eta]*
    Cos[\[Alpha][y, Ee[x, y, z], 
         z]/(\[Xi][\[Kappa][y, z, Ee[x, y, z], V], Ee[x, y, z], V, z, 
           y] - \[Eta][Ee[x, y, z], z]*
           Sin[\[Alpha][y, Ee[x, y, z], z]]) - \[Alpha][y, 
        Ee[x, y, z], z];


     FullSimplify[
     D[\[CapitalPhi][\[Eta][Ee[x, y, z], z], \[Alpha][y, Ee[x, y, z], 
     z], \[Xi][\[Kappa][y, z, Ee[x, y, z], V], Ee[x, y, z], V, z, y]],
     z]] /. z -> 0
```

Comment: It’s probably the FullSimplify that’s taking long. Have you tried calculating the derivative without the simplification step to see if it still takes long?

Comment: @MarcoB..Yes..I believe it is the FullSimplify that was slowing down the whole process..It worked just fine with Simplify..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a better start:

```
Ee[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];

η[Ee_, z_] := Sqrt[(Ee - z)/(Ee + z)];

α[y_, Ee_, z_] := ArcTan[y/Sqrt[Ee^2 - y^2 - z^2]];

κ[y_, z_, Ee_, V_] := Sqrt[y^2 + z^2 - (Ee - V)^2];

ξ[κ_, Ee_, V_, z_, y_] := (κ + y)/(Ee - V + z);

Φ[η_, α_, ξ_] := 2 ArcTan[η Cos[α/(ξ - η Sin[α]) - α]];

dΦ = 
  D[Φ[η[Ee[x, y, z], z], α[y, Ee[x, y, z], z], ξ[κ[y, z, Ee[x, y, z], V], Ee[x, y, z], V, z, 
      y]], z] /. z -> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks  @Henrik Schumacher ...Does the imposition of the condition that all the variables be real necessarily slow things down?

Comment: I don't knot. I'd rather say, it's the `FullSimplify` together with the obfuscated way yiu defined the functions...

Comment: ..Yes..I understand..maybe I was just trying to play safe by defining the functions as above..Thanks